# Calculating Averages Throws an "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" Exception

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, exception

I'm trying to write a gold prospecting program that takes an initial data map in the form of a 2D array which then produces a map with all the likely places for gold marked on it.

However, when calculating the average to determine whether or not to mark the point for prospecting, I get a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" exception thrown at me and the program breaks. How would I go about fixing this? Thank you for any help in advance.

```
for (int i = 1; i < nRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < nCols - 1; j++)
            {
                //it is at the line below where the program breaks
                double average = (data[i - 1, j] + data[i + 1, j] + data[i, j - 1] + data[i, j + 1]) / 4;


                if (data[i, j] > average)
                {
                    map[i, j] = "*";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the tag C is appropriate for this question? C doesn't have exceptions

Comment: Yeah that was my fault, still getting used to an American keyboard so I hit the enter key, thinking I was hitting the hash key.

Comment: `data[i + 1, j]` will most probably be out of range when `i == nRows - 1` that is at the end of the outer loop.

Comment: `data[i + 1, j]` will throw for the last iteration of `i` cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go out of borders of your 2-D array. So change this part of your code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < nCols - 1; j++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 1; i < nRows - 2; i++)                  // NOT from 0 to nRows - 1
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < nCols - 2; j++)          // NOT from 0 to nCols - 1
```

so you omit the borders.